# How to do features extraction of ECG using mean frequency in python?

Tags: python, signal-processing, frequency-analysis, frequency-domain

can you help me to correct this code below?

Here I tried to do features extraction of ecg by calculating the mean frequency.

First, I read the audio with this code:

```
Fs, data = read('ecg_file.wav')
```

output from data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDEHi.jpg)

Then, doing FFT to the data

```
Y = np.abs(rfft(data))
```

output from the fft:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz5mO.jpg)

Now, I want to apply this formula which is the formula of the mean frequency.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WH7m.jpg)

From the reference that I have read, *M* is the length of the frequency bin. To find *P*, I use this code:

```
power_spectrum = Y**2
```

and I'm still confused to calculate the value of *f*j.
Can you guys help to correct the code above?

Comment: You also can consider https://mne.tools/mne-features/ which offer variety of common feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy has a nice operation to get the frequency values from a fourier transformation called `fftfreq` or `rfftfreq` for your example.

```py
import numpy as np
# First get the frequency vector
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(data), Fs)
# Then calculate (weighted) mean

mean_f = np.sum(freq * power_spectrum / np.sum(power_spectrum)) # This should equal to the formula in your image.
```

You don't need to do a elementwise multiplication with numpy arrays.

Comment: a~, so with `rfftfreq` I don't need to find the frequency value for each sample